# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am trying to load xml data to the database as a batch job using spring batch. initially load the data to hsql as in-memory data(worked fine) and now I need to persist the data so I have changed it to use file as db but after changing its showing error **org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE**
As in-memory HSQL is working fine but can't change it to use file as DB in order persist the data
Tried using spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update it didn't work

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/src/main/resources/db/hsql;
spring.datasource.username = "admin" 
spring.datasource.password = "admin"
```

ERROR :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=1077:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\shanil\Desktop\swift_exam\Swift_report_generator\ReportGenerator2022\saa-report-generator\target\classes;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-batch\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-batch-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.10\logback-classic-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.10\logback-core-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.1\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.33\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-core\4.3.5-SNAPSHOT\spring-batch-core-4.3.5-20220212.200001-90.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.1\jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.1\jackson-annotations-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.1\jackson-core-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-core\1.9.0-SNAPSHOT\micrometer-core-1.9.0-20220215.231045-57.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.12\HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\latencyutils\LatencyUtils\2.0.3\LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\javax\batch\javax.batch-api\1.0\javax.batch-api-1.0.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.2\jettison-1.2.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-infrastructure\4.3.5-SNAPSHOT\spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5-20220212.200001-90.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.3.1\spring-retry-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-context-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-tx-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.4.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.7\byte-buddy-1.12.7.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.5\jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.5\txw2-2.3.5.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-data-jpa-2.7.0-20220215.192549-167.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-data-commons-2.7.0-20220215.192059-137.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-orm-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.33\slf4j-api-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-aspects-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mail\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-mail-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-context-support-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\jakarta.mail\1.6.7\jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.1\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.58\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.58\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.58.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.58\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.58.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-web-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-webmvc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-expression-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.0-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.5.2\hsqldb-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-core-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-jcl-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.22\lombok-1.18.22.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\5.3.15\spring-oxm-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.16-SNAPSHOT\spring-beans-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.19\xstream-1.4.19.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\io\github\x-stream\mxparser\1.2.2\mxparser-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\shanil\.m2\repository\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar com.ecsfin.ssb.saareportgenerator.SaaReportGeneratorApplication
11:53:05.069 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@28a2fd34

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.7.0-SNAPSHOT)

2022-02-16 11:53:05.865  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.s.SaaReportGeneratorApplication    : Starting SaaReportGeneratorApplication using Java 15.0.1 on LAPTOP-RODPBL05 with PID 12740 (C:\Users\shanil\Desktop\swift_exam\Swift_report_generator\ReportGenerator2022\saa-report-generator\target\classes started by shanil in C:\Users\shanil\Desktop\swift_exam\Swift_report_generator\ReportGenerator2022\saa-report-generator)
2022-02-16 11:53:05.867  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.s.SaaReportGeneratorApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-16 11:53:06.003  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-02-16 11:53:06.004  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-02-16 11:53:07.225  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-16 11:53:07.254  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-16 11:53:08.456  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-02-16 11:53:08.471  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-16 11:53:08.471  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
2022-02-16 11:53:08.622  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-16 11:53:08.622  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2617 ms
2022-02-16 11:53:08.767  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-02-16 11:53:09.143  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] hsqldb.db.HSQLDB7F0132ED38.ENGINE        : Checkpoint start
2022-02-16 11:53:09.144  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] hsqldb.db.HSQLDB7F0132ED38.ENGINE        : checkpointClose start
2022-02-16 11:53:09.145  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] hsqldb.db.HSQLDB7F0132ED38.ENGINE        : checkpointClose synched
2022-02-16 11:53:09.154  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] hsqldb.db.HSQLDB7F0132ED38.ENGINE        : checkpointClose script done
2022-02-16 11:53:09.162  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] hsqldb.db.HSQLDB7F0132ED38.ENGINE        : checkpointClose end
2022-02-16 11:53:09.164  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] hsqldb.db.HSQLDB7F0132ED38.ENGINE        : Checkpoint end - txts: 1
2022-02-16 11:53:09.175  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2022-02-16 11:53:09.178  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-02-16 11:53:09.344  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-02-16 11:53:09.436  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
2022-02-16 11:53:09.679  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-02-16 11:53:09.855  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
2022-02-16 11:53:10.544  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-02-16 11:53:10.554  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-16 11:53:11.160  WARN 12740 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-02-16 11:53:11.558  WARN 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.batch.JpaBatchConfigurer         : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs. To silence this warning, set 'spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create' to 'default'.
2022-02-16 11:53:11.562  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2022-02-16 11:53:11.594  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2022-02-16 11:53:11.717  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-02-16 11:53:11.789  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-02-16 11:53:11.806  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.s.SaaReportGeneratorApplication    : Started SaaReportGeneratorApplication in 6.716 seconds (JVM running for 8.044)
2022-02-16 11:53:11.809  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2022-02-16 11:53:12.006  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-16 11:53:12.048 ERROR 12740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:751) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1280) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.ecsfin.ssb.saareportgenerator.SaaReportGeneratorApplication.main(SaaReportGeneratorApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE in statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5-20220212.200001-90.jar:4.3.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.isJobInstanceExists(SimpleJobRepository.java:93) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5-20220212.200001-90.jar:4.3.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.isJobInstanceExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5-20220212.200001-90.jar:4.3.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.isJobInstanceExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:206) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:198) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:748) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0-20220214.154729-178.jar:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE in statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1645) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.16-20220215.140500-43.jar:5.3.16-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    ... 53 common frames omitted

2022-02-16 11:53:12.103  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-16 11:53:12.107  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-02-16 11:53:12.110  INFO 12740 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Spring batch Item writer**

```
@Bean
public JpaItemWriter<SAAMessage> saaMessageItemWriter() {
    JpaItemWriter<SAAMessage> writer = new JpaItemWriter();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return writer;
}
```

Comment: Do not use the directory structure of the program files for the database. Use an absolute path on disk for the database so that the same location is used regardless of how you run the Java program.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Boot's auto-configuration only initializes the Spring Batch tables for embedded databases. And when you switch to a file-based instead of an in-memory database, Spring Boot no longer considers the database to be embedded.

You can explicitly enable initialization of the Spring Batch tables by setting the property

```
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

Please also have a look at the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.3/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.batch